# C++ - Return C++11 std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, reference

I have some code like that

```
#define SIZE 10
Class User
{
public:
    std::array<Account, SIZE> getListAccount()
    {
         return listAccount;
    }
private:
    std::array<Account, SIZE> listAccount
}

Class Account
{
public:
    void setUserName(std::string newUSN)
    {
        userName=newUSN;
    }
private:
    string userName;
    string password;
}


int main()
{
     User xxx(.......);
     xxx.getListAccount()[1].setUserName("abc");    // It doesn't effect
     return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the `setUserName()` function call in main change the name in my `xxx` User?

By the way:

- I'm using `std::array` because I want to save data in binary file
- In my actual code, I user char [], not string

Comment: Your getter returns a copy of the array, so the name is just changed in the copy and not in the original.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question, from the formulation it's not clear what you really want. Most definitely you don't want to return either an array or a reference to it.

Comment: You pasted invalid C++ code: `class` must be written all-lowercase and you need to define `class Account` before using it in an `std::array<Account, SIZE>`, and you missed three `;` -- please read how to provide a [mcve]! Also, for less name-pollution, avoid using `#define`. Instead declare a `static const size_t SIZE=10;` or an `enum {SIZE=10};` (both can even be done inside the class where you want to use it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return a reference to the list instead

```
std::array<Account, SIZE> & // << Note the &
User::getListAccount();
```

Or better, don't expose the internal structure

```
Account&
User::getUser(size_t n) 
{
    return listAccount[n];
}
```

Comment: Exposing guts of the entity on an interface is usually not a very good idea (for many reasons).

Comment: Duplicating the account functions in User with an index is also a possibility.  To me there is no clear winner compared to the getUser approach.  Too many duplication can become messy, too many getters too.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::array<Account, SIZE> getListAccount() const {
     return listAccount;
}
```

this returns a *copy* of the array.

```
std::array<Account, SIZE>& getListAccount() {
     return listAccount;
}
std::array<Account, SIZE> const& getListAccount() const {
     return listAccount;
}
```

this returns a reference to the array.

```
template<class T>
struct span_t {
  T* b = 0; T* e = 0;
  span_t()=default;
  span_t(T* s, T* f):b(s),e(f){}
  span_t(T* s, std::size_t l):span_t(s, s+l){}
  T* begin() const{ return b; }
  T* end() const{ return e; }
  T& operator[](std::size_t i)const{ return begin()[i]; }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
};

span_t<Account> getListAccount() {
  return {listAccount.data(), listAccount.size()};
}
span_t<const Account> getListAccount() const {
  return {listAccount.data(), listAccount.size()};
}
```

this returns a wrapper around a pair of pointers that represent a contiguous range of accounts without exposing the underlying data structure used to store the accounts.

Of these three, I'd use the `span_t`.  It has next to zero overhead, and hides information the client has little interest in.